# Creating a soft symbolic link from R on Windows

Tags: r, symlink

I'd like to create a **soft** symbolic link to a file from within R on Windows (with [Mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)). It fails because I cannot tell R to "run it as administrator". Is there any way I can do this?

I did manage to create hard symbolic file links, however:

```
path_src <- file.path(tempdir(), "test.txt")
write("Hello World!", file = path_src)
path_tgt <- file.path(tempdir(), "test_symlink.txt")
shell(sprintf("mklink /H %s %s", 
  normalizePath(path_tgt, mustWork = FALSE),
  normalizePath(path_src)
))
```

Note how the file at `path_tgt` reflects the changes made to `path_src`:

```
write("HELLO WORLD!", file = path_src, append = TRUE)
```

Yet, this fails:

```
path_tgt_2 <- file.path(tempdir(), "test_symlink_2.txt")
> shell(sprintf("mklink /D %s %s", 
  normalizePath(path_tgt_2, mustWork = FALSE),
  normalizePath(path_src)
))
Ihre Berechtigungen reichen nicht aus, um diesen Vorgang auszufhren.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c mklink /D C:\Users\Thyson\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpum73ZU\test_symlink_2.txt C:\Users\Thyson\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpum73ZU\test.txt' had status 1 
2: In shell(sprintf("mklink /D %s %s", normalizePath(path_tgt_2, mustWork = FALSE),  :
  'mklink /D C:\Users\Thyson\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpum73ZU\test_symlink_2.txt C:\Users\Thyson\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpum73ZU\test.txt' Ausführung mit Fehlerkode 1 fehlgeschlagen
```

### Note

Due to a German version of Windows I can't seem to get the errors in English. The first line translates to somewhat along the lines of "*You don't have enough authorization in order to carry out this process*"

Comment: For translations, try: `Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE='en')`

Comment: [This seems post](http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows) to suggest it's not really possible without add-ons.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for the pointer! Kind of sucks that it requires an add-on, but better than nothing ;-) PS: I do have LANGUAGE = "en" (it's my general setting in the .Renviron file for all of my project) and all my other "within R" errors are in fact in Englisch, but the `shell()` command seems to delegate everything to the basic OS level somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run R as administrator. Then when you run "Mklink" from within R, you are the administrator.

Actually, you can also use the R function file.symlink to create symbolic links.

Comment: And how do I explicitly run R as admin? When I open R from within RStudio while being logged in as a Windows user with admin rights, it does not work

Comment: Try to run RStudio as the administrator.

Comment: Even if you has logged in as a Windows user with admin rights, to run RStudio as administrator, you should right click the icon of Rstudio on the Desktop and then choose "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 1):

Since [2016 (Windows 10 Insiders build 14972)](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/), you can also make symbolic links without administrator rights if you enable the developer mode (in Settings>Update and Security>For developers).

This works in the Windows console with [`mklink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink), but it doesn't seem that R's `file.symlink()` works (as of R 4.0.3), possibly because of the `dwFlags` that needs to be set.

For calling it from R, I needed to add `"` when the path contains spaces:

```
shell(sprintf('mklink "%s" "%s"', 
              normalizePath(link, mustWork = FALSE),
              normalizePath(original)
))
```

For directories, you can also consider the use of `Sys.junction()` which is somewhat equivalent to symlinks.